# Cognitive Image Search API - Get only transparent background images

Tags: image, api, search, transparency, azure-cognitive-services

I am currently trying to use the Cognitive Image Search API - V5.

My question is quite simple, is there a way to filter the result of the request to get only images with transparent background ? (Not only filtering by file extension, some png are not transparent). Obviously I didn't find anything useful in the doc or on the web.

I would appreciate if you guys could give me some tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular search parameter is not available. the current filters that are available are listed below.

aspect—Filter images by aspect ratio (for example, standard or wide screen images)

color—Filter images by color or black and white

freshness—Filter images by age (for example, images discovered by Bing in the past week)

height—Filter images by height

imageContent—Filter images by content (for example, images that show only a person's face)

imageType—Filter images by type (for example, clip art or animated GIFs)

license—Filter images by the type of license that applies to the image

size—Filter images by size, such as small images up to 200x200 pixels

width—Filter images by width

You can see further information for [Bing Image Search query parameters here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760791.aspx#imagetype)

Comment: Thanks for the reply